# Build hash not changing when I build my react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am running "npm run build" on my react app. In the build output folder, it creates new chunk files, but the hash has not changed (e.g. /static/js/main.2860365d.chunk.js). I thought webpack would just change it every time. What causes the hash to change and how do I force it to change on build?

Comment: Hey did you find somting about hashed code build generate ?